# Preview blogpost changes in Composite before publishing

Tags: .net, content-management-system, composite

Is it possible to preview a new Blog post in Composite C1 before publishing? At the moment there is only a save option which publishes the post instantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it was fixed today. please check Composite.Community.Blog v.1.7.4. This version works under Composite C1 v.3.1